# typedef of a template with a template type as its parameter

Tags: c++, typedef

Im having a problem with a typedef below, I can seem to get it right:

```
template <typename T>
  struct myclass1 {
  static const int member1 = T::GetSomeInt();
};

template <int I>
struct myclass2 {
  typedef myclass1< myclass2<I> > anotherclass;
  static int GetSomeInt();
};

anotherclass MyObj1; // ERROR here not instantiating the class
```

When I try and initialize a anotherclass object, it gives me an error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? There seems to be a problem with my typedef.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks
Bryan

Comment: Do you want template <int I> or <I> ?

Comment: Im sorry, I edited my answer and explained better.

Comment: There is aproblem with your `anotherclass MyObj1;` declaration.
First, you cannot use it this way for it is an internal type of `myclass2`, so you need `myclass2< sometype >::anotherclass MyObj1;`. Secondary, `template <int I>` is an ussue. What do you expect when I is let's say `10`?  You will call `10:GetSomeInt();` and this is wrong.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Your second point is wrong. `myclass<3>::GetSomeInt()` is perfectly valid, and that's what the `member1` value in `myclass1` will call when you instantiate a `myclass2<3>::anotherclass`.

Comment: @KevinBallard: OOookay, looks like there was some change. Now T is myclass<I> so we will be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to `anotherclass` directly. That name doesn't exist at that scope. You need to declare your variable as

```
myclass2<some_int>::anotherclass MyObj1;
```

where `some_int` is whatever integer value you want to parameterize `myclass2` with.

I think you'll also need to mark `myclass2<I>::GetSomeInt()` as being `constexpr` so it can be used in the initializer of `myclass1<T>::member1`.

With those tweaks, the following code compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct myclass1 {
    static const int member1 = T::GetSomeInt();
};

template<int I>
struct myclass2 {
    typedef myclass1<myclass2<I>> anotherclass;
    constexpr static int GetSomeInt() { return I; };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    myclass2<3>::anotherclass obj;
    std::cout << obj.member1 << std::endl;
}
```

Note, this requires C++11 for `constexpr`. If you want C++03 then I don't think your `myclass1<T>::member1` is legal.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `typedef` using `myclass1` and passing in a templatised class as the parameter. Hence you need use template template parameters. This means that the declaration of `myclass1` should be changed to to tell the compiler that `T` in `template <typename T>` is itself a template class.

See if changing the following code

```
template <typename T>
  struct myclass1 {
  static const int member1 = T::GetSomeInt();
};
```

to this fixes the problem:

```
template < template <typename BasicType> class T>
  struct myclass1 {
  static const int member1 = T::GetSomeInt();
};
```

Comment: With the tweaks mentioned in my answer, the code compiles just fine. You don't need a template template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I thought it should have compiled as it is unless a default template argument is specified.